# Using CONCATENATE with Google forms and sheets

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-forms, array-formulas

I have a survey going out with Google Forms, but to analyse the results, I would need to concatenate some cells. However, due to the nature of Google Forms, whenever a new response is recorded, a new row is added. I've read around, looking at different forums and tutorials, but can't seem to find anything that works.

Some of the places I've looked are:
[concatenate column values for each row that gets added after google form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390181/concatenate-column-values-for-each-row-that-gets-added-after-google-form-submiss)

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/0Os52U-0i1k

So what I would need help with is if it's possible to concatenate results from a Google Form without having to manually copy the formula in the cells whenever there are new responses. I've tried ArrayFormula, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Google? Do you have to use all uppercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayFormula(A2:A & B2:B)` should do the trick.
Note that the formula will persist even if you put it directly at the end of the form and then add a new field.
It will just be shifted to the right, so you don't need to worry about taking care of that when you modify your form.

Answer (score 0):

The CONCATENATE function is a Google spreadsheet function that combines two or more text strings into a single string. It appears in the dropdown menu for functions above cell A1, and when you select it, it places an =CONCATENATE()= formula in the selected cell.
Note that you may need to replace spaces with "&" if your text has spaces.
In order to perform this operation on Google Forms though, you will need to set up Form Embeds by making sure you have the input type of "google form embed." When embedded forms are enabled, there is no need for individual cells within a google sheet workbook with custom formulas next to each question result button as they're all being calculated.

You can find more info on CONCATENATE by referring to [this](https://www.exceltrick.com/how_to/concatenate-in-excel/).

Comment: You're explaining a lot about what concatenate does, but it doesn't look like you've addressed the original question very well. Further, you've linked to an excel help site for a Google Sheets question.